# I can't select the strip in Video Sequencer

Tags: video-sequence-editor

Whenever I press it just splits the strip where my cursor is. It worked just fine but suddenly started doing it without me knowing how i activated it. Help

Answer (score 2):

somehow you started the "blade" functionality.

Either press "W" to deactivate or tap this upper button here:

[image]

You can get the toolbar by tapping "T"